# How do I get a buried variable from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

This is probably a very novice question, but I am a very novice programmer, so here goes...

I am using GAS and Google Books to get the url for a book cover using this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers+inauthor:keyes&country=US"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

From my limited knowledge, I tried using this to get the proper URL:

```
Logger.log(data.items.imageLinks.smallThumbnail);
```

but it just returns an error. Is there something missing or a different way to get the variable I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `data.items` is an array of 10 elements, therefore you have to index that.

### If you want to access the first element:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers+inauthor:keyes&country=US"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  console.log(data.items.length)
  Logger.log(data.items[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail);
}
```

### If you want to access all elements and store it in an array:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers+inauthor:keyes&country=US"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var items = data.items;
  var smallThumbnails = items.map(x=>x.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail);
  Logger.log(smallThumbnails);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[http://books.google.com/books/content?id=gK98gXR8onwC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api, http://books.google.com/books/content?id=LRlCAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api, http://books.google.com/books/content?id=Fgn65IL3q4wC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api, http://books.google.com/books/content?id=3vFDvgAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api, http://books.google.com/books/content?id=gK98gXR8onwC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api, http://books.google.com/books/content?id=F1wgqlNi8AMC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api, http://books.google.com/books/content?id=64tuPwAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&source=gbs_api, http://books.google.com/books/content?id=wAUiAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api, http://books.google.com/books/content?id=7hLQ_F0obXAC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api, http://books.google.com/books/content?id=tVxnDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&edge=curl&source=gbs_api]
```